# What does Application Data tab contain in Cloud Hub?

Tags: mule, cloud

I'm working on mule 4.1.5, anypoint 7.1.3

I have gone through some documents and came to know that Application Data tab in cloud Hub contains Object store data in key value pair.

In my interface/flow i used object store and stored the value. When i deploy code on cloud hub i don't see any key value pair in Application Tab. 
[image]
I achieved my desire output when i check use object store v2 in settings.

what is the purpose of Application Data then ? is there any relation between object store and application data ? when i check use object store v2 Application Data tab disappears
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ‘application data’ is for object store v1. And the option is renamed ‘Object Store’ in V2 . It contains all application data stored in your object stores in your mule application such as watermarks, cache entries etc.

For V1 OS you need to reference the Cloudhub specific object store for it to be persisted and be visisble in 'Application Data' using the store named '_defaultUserObjectStore':

```
<objectstore:config name="Objectstore" objectStore-ref="_defaultUserObjectStore" />
```

Good article on object store here:

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Persistent-Object-Store-in-CloudHub

Comment: thanks a lot, so i need not use 'Application Data' tab as i'm working with 'Object Store V2' ?

Comment: For v2, use ‘Object Store’.